# Convert Timestamp to NSDate not working

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have come across a lot of links on stackoverflow and tried to implement code to convert timestamp in this format **2013-07-20T12:23:54.411+05:30** to NSDate of this format

July 20, 2013 (Tuesday) 12:23:54 Or 1 minute ago, 2 days ago format.

I have implemented the following code. The toDate is nil i.e date1 is giving nil value. Seems like Xcode is being sarcastic for this issue

> I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean
>   with a nil toDate? An exception has been avoided for now. A few of
>   these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then
>   further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing
>   results from the nil.

Could anyone tell me where i have gone wrong?

```
     NSDateFormatter *dateForm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateForm setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ssssZ"];
    [dateForm setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    [dateForm setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSDate *date1 = [dateForm dateFromString:string];
    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    // gets the difference between the current date and also the date and time in the timestamp of the data
    NSDateComponents *diffComps = [cal components:unitFlags fromDate:date2 toDate:date1 options:0];

    int year = ABS([diffComps year]);
    int month = ABS([diffComps month]);
    int day = ABS([diffComps day]);
    int hour = ABS([diffComps hour]);
    int minute = ABS([diffComps minute]);
    int seconds = ABS([diffComps second]);
    NSString *displayTime;

    if (year == 0) {

        if (month == 0) {

            if (day == 0) {

                if (hour == 0){

                    if (minute == 0) {

                        displayTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"about %d secs ago",seconds];
                    }
                    else {

                        displayTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"about %d mins ago",minute];
                    }
                }
                else {

                    displayTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"about %d hours ago",hour];
                }
            }
            else {
                displayTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"about %d days ago",day];
            }
        }
        else {

            displayTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"about %d months ago",month];
        }
    }
    else {

        displayTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"about %d years ago",year];
    }
```

**EDIT:** This works fine with a string that i have created in the appdelegate. But not the string I have created in a singleton class.

Comment: "gone wrong" with what?

Comment: Your date format is wrong.  Find the doc for NSDateFormatter, then follow a chain about 6 links long to get to the date format codes.  The answer is there.  I'd point you to it, but then you wouldn't know how to find it yourself.  (Or you can search SO for one of the several dozen times in the past when this question has been asked.)

Comment: i have searched a lot of links on SO and google.. Mostly all the solutions are for UNIX timestamp. I'm aware that my date format is wrong but i'm not getting the solution to whats right.

Comment: You probably want four `ZZZZ` characters for the time zone in the date format.

Comment: I have tried that also :( :( no luck... I'm sure its something very minor.. but not sure what.. I just want to parse that timestamp to something displayable..

Comment: How about `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSssssZZZZ"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct time format; I would suggest this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ
```

Comment: sorry for messing with your format. But according to `NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:[df dateFromString:@"2013-07-20T12:23:54.411+05:30"]]);` it should be correct now.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Not a problem.  Cheers.

Comment: Just one more clarification, This code works for one string and not the other which has the same format of time... any idea why?

Comment: @SharanyaKM Have you used the updated format, as provided by Matthias Bauch?